# Wordpress Theme loses all Line breaks after upload

Tags: wordpress, themes, line-breaks

Yesterday, i Worked on a Wordpress theme in the Editor, to lazy to do the small changes offline...
Today, i downloaded the files and made some changes... after reuploading it via FTP, all Line Breaks in my Code went missing! its all a big block of code now!
At least Wordpress interprets it als such, in my IDE (Netbeans) as well as other Text editors, the code is fine...
How can this be? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks have 3 styles : UNIX , Mac and Windows. You must have mixed up the line break modes. To convert line break styles, use advanced text editor such as Notepad++.